# Files that are older than 6pm on a Saturday

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to grab all files within a directory where their modified date is after 6pm and Saturday.

I have something like this:

```
for filename in os.listdir(dir):
    print filename
    # 2019-05-14 16:35:13.121157
    full_datetime =  datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(dir + "/" + filename))
```

But I'm having difficulties converting the `getmtime` into a state where I can check the day of the week and time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is actually what you need; your desired condition is

```py
full_datetime.weekday() == 5 and full_datetime.hour >= 18
```

Comment: The `dayofweek()` method does not work on my computer. However, `isoweekday()` does the trick (with 1 for Monday,..., 7 for Sunday)

Comment: thanks @fuglede. @horace, I am in the same boat. `isoweekday()` worked for me.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo: I actually mean to use plain `weekday`.